# Polyhedron and Gravity

Tags: geometry, transformation, polyhedra

I am currently looking for a method for pulling a polyhedron to the xy-plane.
This means, that an arbitrary polyhedron (i.e. with holes and concavities) is not simply projected to the xy-plane, but "melts/sinks down" filling holes and lateral concavities, just as if strong gravity pulled it down to the surface. The resulting polyhedron has the same volume and the same projection to the xy-plane as the original.

The goal is to find a way to calculate the "thickness" of the polyhedron in the z-direction for a given x/y coordinate (a function `thickness(x, y)`), which could be determined easily from the resulting polyhedron.

With a "flattened" polyhedron you have a set of plane equations which make up the "top" of the polyhedron. Then you just have to insert x/y into the appropriate plane equation to get the height, which equals the thickness.

Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: I guess the points of the polyhedron only move straight down, and stop when they hit an existing point or the floor? That is the only model I can think of that satisfies your constraints. The "melts/sinks down under strong gravity" metaphor is a bit confusing -- if one imagines the polyhedron made of rubber or bubblegum then it might shrink in volume, or if it was made of sand it would spread out and not remain within the original projection.

Comment: Anyway, if my first interpretation is correct then the thickness is just given by the total length of the parts of the line $\{(x,y,z) : z\in\mathbb R\}$ that lie inside the polyhedron. If you can find all the intersections of the polyhedral surface with a vertical line, then you can compute the desired thickness.

Comment: @Rahul Yes, this is correct, but I try to find a (closed) formula for this without the need of calculating intersections.

Comment: I don't see how that's possible (even if you had the "flattened" polyhedron you'd still need to do point location tests to compute the thickness at any point), but good luck.

Comment: @Rahul No, with a "flattened" polyhedron you have a bunch of plane equations which make up the top of the polyhedron. Then you just have to insert x/y into the appropriate plane equation to get the height, which equals the thickness

Comment: Finding the appropriate plane among many other planes makes this approach about as difficult as calculating intersections.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Not at all! You just have to find in the 2d projection of the planes to the xy-plane the appropriate area for a given xy coordinate. This is very efficient to calculate with an rtree

Comment: You may store the faces of the original polyhedron in a similar precomputed structure... but I guess you are right, it is better to "flatten" the whole thing somehow.

Comment: How does querying an R-tree fit with your stated desire to "find a (closed) formula for this without the need of calculating intersections"?

Comment: @Rahul It doesn't, but it is the best I can come up with; for a given x/y coordinate first efficiently look up the correct plane equation, then calculate the z coordinate. But I am open for other methods, i.e. a completely closed formula.

Comment: Are you assuming that the volume of the polyhedron remains constant throughout? You also seem to imply that the hull of the "slumped" figure will be a prism. If so then there is possibly an easier way: Find the convex hull of the polyhedron, which will do the filling-in for you, and then find the area of its shadow on the ground plane. Divide the volume by that area and you have your final thickness.